# Doctrine 2 - Get Entity manager from class

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I can't figure out how it is best to get the Doctrine Entity Manager from my service layers, and template controller..

I thinking of making a singleton so i always can get the Entity manager, but is it the right way to do it?

**Updated: I'll take an example**

```
class Auth
{
    const USER_ENTITY_NAME = 'Entities\User';

    private $isVerified = FALSE;

    public static function login($email, $password, $em, $rememberMe = false)
    {
        if(empty($email) OR empty($password))
        {
            // new login response

        }

        if($user = (self::getUser($email, $password, $em) !== null))
        {
            $sreg = SessionRegistry::instance();
            $sreg->set("user_id", $user->getId());
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public static function getUser($email, $password, $em)
    {
        return $em->getRepository(
            USER_ENTITY_NAME );
    }
```

What i cant figure out is where i should get the user from? so i doesn't have to send the entity manager as an parameter.

Comment: All repositories always have access to the entity manager, via `->getEntityManager()`, so most people tend to do the work within custom repositories.  That's what I've seen mostly anyhow and what I use myself.

Comment: Okay but how to get the repository from another class? i need the entity manager again... I think i'm missing something here, i have a authorization class where i need to get the user to see if the user exists.

Comment: Basically, within Entities, the only other entities you have access to are associations and anything passed in to any methods from outside.  In a repository, you have access to the entity manager, so you can get to the database at large.

Comment: I have uploaded an example of what i try to do.. You say i should get it from entities? i'm not sure i follow, the entities is just an representation of the object so i can't put a getter in there right?

Comment: So you are talking about access to the entity manager within your own application code, not in your Doctrine code?  Entirely up to you in that case, a singleton would be fine if you only need a single entity manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) over singleton.

I don't know which environment are you using Doctrine in, but I assume it being MVC - then any Controller should have access to the entity manager, either by passing it as a constructor argument, either by injecting it with a setter.

This way you can fetch stuff *from* the controller, and pass it to the `Auth` class eventually.

Anyway I think that authorization doesn't need an external class - I'd just write a `loginAction` method in a controller, get username and password from HTTP request and make the usual considerations [fetch the user / check if password is right], then store something in session in case of succesful login.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.. I made an dependency class so the entity manager always is available for my controllers..